# border-radius for progress bar progress

Tags: jquery, css

When the bar is not yet to reach 100%, I want to keep the edge without rounded effect.. What I did is use if then change the css of the bar, but it's one step behind.. take a look

http://jsfiddle.net/xjkhH/

you need to hit once more even it reached 100%

```
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    $progress_bar = $('#progressbarr');

    //convert to percent
    var progressbar_width;


    progressbar_width = Math.floor(100 * ($progress_bar.find('div').width()) / $progress_bar.width());

    var i = progressbar_width + 10; // change in percent

    if (i < 101) {


        $progress_bar.find('div').css('width', (i + '%'));

        $progress_bar.find('span').text(i + '%');


    } else {
        $progress_bar.find('div').css('border-top-right-radius', '4px');
        $progress_bar.find('div').css('border-bottom-right-radius', '4px');

    }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep it simple This is all you need (CSS):

```
overflow:hidden;
```

for your `#progressbarr` :)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xjkhH/4/)**

Comment: but what is the logic? overflow:hidden; means it hide the things that's over limit?

Answer (score 4):

You could just do that:

```
if (i <= 100) {


        $progress_bar.find('div').css('width', (i + '%'));

        $progress_bar.find('span').text(i + '%');
        if(i === 100)
            $(this).triggerHandler('click');

    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xjkhH/2/)

Comment: will this line  $(this).triggerHandler('click'); effect other event?

Comment: triggerHandler('click') will fired all handlers bound to matched element for click event only, without any event propagation. Is it your question?

Comment: if I have another click event besides this one, it will not fire right? because I assume $(this) apply to only this certain scope

Comment: no $(this) is the DOM element wrapped in jquery object, all click handlers bound to this element will be fired. If you want to trigger only specific handler, use event namespace

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xjkhH/1/)**

Just add the below code before your else statement

```
$progress_bar.find('div').css('border-top-right-radius', '4px');
$progress_bar.find('div').css('border-bottom-right-radius', '4px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use following code

```
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    $progress_bar = $('#progressbarr');

    //convert to percent
    var progressbar_width;


    progressbar_width = Math.floor(100 * ($progress_bar.find('div').width()) / $progress_bar.width());

    var i = progressbar_width + 10; // change in percent

    if (i < 101) {


        $progress_bar.find('div').css('width', (i + '%'));

        $progress_bar.find('span').text(i + '%');
        if( i == 100) {
            $progress_bar.find('div').css('border-top-right-radius', '4px');
        $progress_bar.find('div').css('border-bottom-right-radius', '4px');
        }

    }

    // if
});
```